# GLUT timer function

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to get my tokens on a board game to fall slowly. Right now, they fall, but they fall so fast. How could I implement the timer function in my code? Right now I do a loop, that updates the y coordinate of glTranslate. But it is still too fast! the top y is the y coordinate where I press on the screen, and the bottomy is the coordinates of the lowest open spot for a token.

```
col =0;

double bottomy = 0;
int row = 0;

circlex = (double)x / width ;
circley = (double)y / height ;

row = board.getRow(col) + 1;
bottomy = 500 - (25*row);

for( double topy = y ; topy <= bottomy; topy += 2 ){
    glTranslatef(circlex, circley, 0.0f);
    circley += .0000000000000000001;
    display();
}        

r = board.makeMove(col);
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more code? I see at least two problems here: 1) If all of this code is part of the `glutDisplayFunc`, then it is highly likely that you only see the final outcome and no intermediate steps since the buffers are not swapped. 2) Unless you reset the model matrix inside of display(), you add up the transformations instead of replacing them with the current `circley` value.

Comment: All of this code is a part of my mouse function, which is for when the users presses down on the left button to make move. I think my issue is with the world coordinates for openGL. How would I go about converting my mouse coordinates to world coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`glutTimerFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html) to execute a function at a regular time period. This has the signature

```
void glutTimerFunc(unsigned int msecs,
                   void (*func)(int value),
                   value);
```

For example if your drawing function was

```
void UpdateTokens(int time);
```

Then you could call an update every 0.5 seconds with the following call (where `current_time` was the current simulation time)

```
glutTimerFunc(500, UpdateTokens, current_time);
```

For more precise timing, I would recommend using [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) instead, and performing your timing using things like [`std::chrono::duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) with a [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock).

Comment: `std::chrono::stead_clock` should be `std::chrono::steady_clock`

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem here is how glut works. Basically, the user only gets a image presented at the end of the main loop. As long as you do not return from the mouse function, nothing is presented on screen. You can solve the problem by transferring the work to the display function and distribute the translation across multiple frames:

global variables:

```
double circlex = 0, circley = 0, bottomy = 0;
bool isfalling = false;
int topy = 0;
```

mouse_func:

```
if (isfalling == false) //Prevents the user from clicking during an animation
{
    circlex = (double)x / width ;
    circley = (double)y / height ;

    int row = board.getRow(col) + 1;
    bottomy = 500 - (25*row);
    topy = y;

    isfalling = true;
}
```

display_func:

```
if (isfalling)
{
    circley += .0000000000000000001;
    topy += 2;

    if (topy >= bottomy)
        isfalling = false;
}

glTranslatef(circlex, circley, 0.0f);
display();
```